# A continuous distribution function (in measure theory sense) can be used to define uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

I am working on exercise from Probability: Theory and Examples by Durrett.

If $F = P(X \le x)$ is continuous, then $Y=F(X)$ has a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$, that is if $y \in [0,1]$, $P(Y \le y) = y$.

Following one idea appeared in the book, I suspect by letting $G(x) = \sup_{y} \{ y \colon F(y) \le x \}$ should lead to the result. Then
\begin{align*}
P( Y \le y ) = P( \{ \omega: F(X(\omega)) \le y \} ) = P( \{ \omega: X(\omega) \le G(y)\} ) = F \circ G(y).
\end{align*}

It seems to me by definition $F \circ G(y) \le y$ and for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $F( G(y) + \varepsilon ) > y$, by right continuity I conclude $F\circ G (y) \ge y$.

My argument should be flawed since I am not using the continuity of $F$ here. However I am too blind to see it. Could anyone please point me out? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I think I know where I was wrong. By definition, we could not conclude $F \circ G(y) \le y$. We need the continuity from left here. Since if $z \to G(y)^{-}$ from the left, and $F(z) \le y$, it does not necessarily have $F\circ G(y) \le y$ for it could have a jump at $G(y)$. Any validation to this thinking is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You need left-continuity in exactly the way you've mentioned to conclude that $F(G(y)) \le y$. Your argument that $F(G(y)) \ge y$ using right-continuity is also correct.

Without left-continuity the situation looks like the following. Take $F(x)$ to be $0$ for $x < 0$ and $F(x) = 1$ for $x \ge 0$. Then $G(y) = 0$ for $0 \le y < 1$ and $G(1) = \infty$. Notice that if $y < 1$ then $F(G(y)) = F(0) = 1 \not\le y$.

Properties of the function $G$ are discussed in the article [A note on generalized inverses](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~embrecht/ftp/generalized_inverse_springer) by Paul Embrechts and Marius Hofert.